# Does java synchronized methods synchronizes on object or uses flag

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I've read article about [Java bytecode](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/).
Here work of synchronized methods is described as

> When the synchronized method modifier is present, as in top1, the acquisition and subsequent release of the lock is not done with the monitorenter and monitorexit opcodes. Instead, when the JVM invokes a method, it checks for the ACC_SYNCHRONIZED property flag.

And at the same time I am reading Brian Goetz's 'Concurrency in practise', where he says

> A synchronized method is shorthand for a synchronized block that spans an entire method body, and whose lock is the object on which the method is being invoked. (Static synchronized methods use the Class object for the lock.)

So, first source says that no monitor was taken on object in synchronized method and second source sais that for synchronized method lock on object was used.
I believe, that both sources are correct but could somebody describe me, what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concurrency in Practice's answer says how the implementation *behaves*.  The first version explains how it's *implemented.*  They work exactly the same way in practice.

> So, first source says that no monitor was taken on object in synchronized method

No, it doesn't.  It says the monitor is taken in a different way.